# Out-of-view inbox items can still be selected in mobile view

Tags: bug, mobile-web, global-inbox

This bug is weird and hard to describe, so I'll demonstrate instead. These screenshots are of the stock Android browser. **You can click any of these screenshots for a full view.**

Here's my inbox (left), and scrolled down a little (right). You can see that the fourth and fifth items are a comment and the Arqade elections notification. Notice that in the left screenshot, these are out of view (except for the very top of the comment notification).

[image] [image]

However, if I touch the area **below the inbox** - where the questions are! - I can still select these inbox items, and I *will* be directed to that comment and the Arqade elections. Regardless of whether the inbox has already ended, the browser still considers the items to be there.

[image] [image]

Comment: I can't repro this, can you verify and/or give me a hint on how to make it happen?

Comment: Use the Android stock browser (this is a HTC One with Android 4.4.2 if it makes a difference). And... Click outside/below the opened inbox. Your click highlight won't line up with the questions (maybe) and will take you to an inbox item that wasn't in view. There isn't any other trick to it, I noticed it because I couldn't tap a question in view below the inbox whilst the inbox was open.

Comment: I've just re-checked and it does still happen.

Comment: It doesn't happen with a Samsung S4 with stock browser -- seems to be specific to your setup. Can you see if you can repro in Chrome by any chance?

Comment: I cannot repro this in Chrome. The ones I can repro it in are: the stock browser (named "Internet" on this phone) and Dolphin browser.

Comment: We are changing a bit the way the mobile site works to make it more similar to the mobile apps. This will likely fix this. I will mark as status-review so we keep track of what we need to fix, but I won't fix it for now.

Comment: Sure; thank you. :) If the notifications turn into a side menu that sounds like it'd resolve this via the entire cause going away.

Comment: Yeah, we're likely headed that way.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the mobile-web view is [officially deprecated](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/367609/622284) and thus this will never be changed/fixed.