# Badge bullet vertical alignment does not looking center in mobile UI

Tags: support, bug, design, badges, mobile-web

In the *[Marshal badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/what-are-the-badges-i-can-earn-on-each-site-and-what-are-the-exact-criteria-for/188732#188732)* bullet (circle) vertically not center (red mark 3) and also it does not looking vertical center on `badge numbers` to me (red mark 2)

Also I think it needs some padding right after the bullet (red mark 1).

[image]

Comment: Bullets don’t appear this large for me, Firefox Nighlty 93.0a1.

Comment: Browser and version, please

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Deprecating our mobile views](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/367609/deprecating-our-mobile-views)

Comment: Samsung galaxy mobile and google chrome browser

Comment: What do you mean by "verbally not center" and "does not looking vertical center" (two instances)? It seems incomprehensible. Can you [fix it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/posts/368494/edit)?