# Is the "mobile" link on some pages broken or is it now redundant?

Tags: support, mobile-web

On my Android phone (using Google app version 12.41.19.23.arm64), I have the option to switch between "full site" and "mobile" views.

This switching functionality works perfectly well on the *Questions*, and on my *Activity* and *Settings* pages for both main and Meta sites. However:

- When I'm in "mobile" view and select *Tags*, *Users*, *Badges*, *Ask* or *Review Queues* they all go directly to the "full site" view - and then despite there being a link to "mobile", selecting it makes no discernable difference to what is displayed.

Switching between Enable/Disable Responsiveness options also make no difference, nor does putting my phone in "desktop" mode.

So: Is the "mobile" link on some pages broken or is it now redundant? If the latter should it be removed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The 'mobile web' interface is only available for a select few pages of the website; of course, they are the most used ones (especially by casual visitors and anonymous users). It has now been deprecated in favour of the new responsive design, for which [the plan](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/367609/295232) was to have everything ready by the end of this year. The company will then, at some point in time, switch off the 'mobile' version entirely and the link with be removed from the footer.

The link is shown on all pages because it's part of a common footer shared by all pages. It is not broken in that if you use it on e.g. https://meta.stackexchange.com/review and then go to the home page, you'll notice you've switched to mobile mode. So it's more of a toggle 'please show me the mobile version of all pages, when available'.