# An Overflow Blog page is over-sized and extends beyond the edges of my screen

Tags: bug, blog, the-overflow

The title and first paragraph of the Blog page [A Day in the Penalty Box](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/04/06/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/) over-extends beyond my screen's margins while viewing it via the Google app on an Android phone<sup>1</sup>:

[image]

I've not been able to repoduce this on any other Blog page, and all those I've checked have render correctly, viz:

[image]

<sup>1</sup>The Blog does not offer me the option to switch between "mobile" and "full site" views so I assume it falls outside of the ongoing work for [deprecating our mobile views](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/367609/deprecating-our-mobile-views).

Comment: I noticed this a while ago on my phone and was going to report it on meta but forgot. Chrome on Android 11.

Comment: The blog isn't really 'run' on SE, it's an outsourced WP instance. While SE devs probably do the theming and other things to an extent, it's a different scope from the sites proper