# Occasionally reset to mobile view on phone

Tags: bug, mobile-web

From time to time opening any of SE site pages on my phone leads to show them in mobile view:

> [image: mobile MSE]

Despite I selected full site and enabled responsiveness early before. It seems that cookies are outdated or something ... but I'm still logged in.

According to the question [Deprecating our mobile views](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/367609/339911) mobile web is deprecated. So can we please stop switching views to mobile automatically at least for ones who are logged in and set "full site" before?

Comment: Blame cookies expiring.

Comment: @Luuklag and we need to go deeper ... to blame time at all.