# How can I switch to the full site when the mobile view only has the "Mobile" link and doesn't provide the "Full site" link?

Tags: support, mobile-web, full-site

[The mobile view has been deprecated since 14 Feb](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/367609/241919)... or so it seems.

Catija mentioned this on [The Tavern](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/9130927#9130927),

> So... I have a guess... a few days ago we got rid of the mobile view, right? But we didn't get rid of the button in the footer... so, what happens when you click the button??? The system seems to get confused... and one of the side effects is... not showing some elements of the page.
>
> Yeah, we just got rid of the mobile views a day or two ago.
>
> Oh crap.
>
> DO NOT CLICK THE "MOBILE" BUTTON IN THE FOOTER!!!
>
> You can't go back.
>
> It's supposed to switch between mobile and full site... but it thinks you're always on the full site, so there's no way to get back to full site and get the flagging ability back.

While the mobile view is still the default view on mobile browsers, the user is now stuck in limbo in "full mobile" view. And those who want to find and test bug reports are also stuck.

Is there a workaround to switch to the full site?

Comment: Yes, must love my flair for drama. :P I'm just glad it's not so difficult to get rid of the cookie because not being able to flag comments on MSE would have spared so many people my wrath. ;)

Comment: Does using the "Request Mobile Site" option that exists in the browser itself fix it? I couldn't duplicate the issue to test it.

Comment: Given that the [Mobile link has been removed completely as of 2022-03-02](/q/367609/289905), is this [tag:status-completed]?

Answer (score 11):

The "Mobile" link calls a JavaScript function `StackExchange.switchMobile("on")`.

To revert to the full site, calling `StackExchange.switchMobile("off")` is sufficient.

On most browsers, this can be done by entering `javascript:StackExchange.switchMobile("off")` on the address bar and enter.

Comment: You can also go into your browser cookie settings and remove the "theme" setting (on desktop).

Comment: Thanks, this works. However, I find that I need to call the function on all the SE sites I visit on my mobile browser. Is there a workaround?

Comment: @BigBrother no, this is per-site setting, sadly.