# Linked and related questions require requesting desktop site when on a phone

Tags: bug, status-completed, related-questions, linked-questions, responsive-design

I [searched](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/linked-questions+responsive-design) but I don't think it was reported.

When viewing a post on a phone (e.g. iPhone using Safari), the responsive design does not show the linked and related questions unless desktop site is requested. Example:

> [image]
> Right screenshot is taken after requesting desktop site (click to view)

Comment: Is this still this bug? [How can I switch to the full site when the mobile view only has the "Mobile" link and doesn't provide the "Full site" link?](/q/376343/289905)

Comment: Congrats, you found a remnant of the now dead mobile web, and you're stuck on the mobile web view. Follow the steps [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/376343/how-can-i-switch-to-the-full-site-when-the-mobile-view-only-has-the-mobile-lin) to get rid of the mobile view, and be careful not to tap the "mobile" link again. (For some very odd reason SE won't remove it, maybe they think people love the thrill of the risk.)

Comment: @SebastianSimon Yes, it is still a bug. It looks like they haven't removed the mobile view completely. The responsive site is not actually responsive! :-(