# Pluralization issue: "View all 1 bounties"

Tags: bug, status-completed, bounties, plurals, activity

In the user "[Activity](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/356843/justin?tab=topactivity)" page, in the "Summary" tab, there is a pluralization issue in the section for bounties. If only one bounty has been earned, then clicking on the "Earned" subtab shows the following:

[image: Screenshot of the profile page displaying the pluralization issue.]

> ### Earned bounty (1)
>
> View all 1 bounties

Here, "View all 1 bounties" should be "View 1 bounty".

Similarly, if only one bounty has been offered, then clicking on the "Offered" subtab shows:

> ### Offered bounty (1)
>
> View all 1 bounties

Presumably, the same pluralization bug occurs in the "Active" subtab if there is only one active bounty.

Note that this issue occurs only in the "Summary" tab of the Activity page, and not in the "Bounties" tab.

Comment: Obligatory [reference to history](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/236746/what-is-the-story-of-jeff-atwood-and-the-pluralization-bug)

Comment: I see something very different on your profile: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zc2iQ.png). This most likely means you're somehow stuck on the now dead mobile view, which has totally different view, and tons of bugs. Please follow the steps [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/376344/152859) and I'm pretty sure you'll see the correct view, with no pluralization bug.

Comment: @rene history indeed, the OP is seeing some old view, likely mobile view. Part of SE history. ;)

Comment: @ShadowWizardHatesOmicron: I guess I wasn't clear. Don't click on "View all 1 bounties".  The screenshot you took is after you clicked on the link.

Comment: Oh, OK, thanks. I'll try to see if I can somehow edit to make it more clear so others won't get confused as well. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Caught this issue in [Pluralization issue in the "Tags", "Responses" & "Votes" tabs on the Activity page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/376912/209031)

Thanks again for the report - Here's an S Friend:

[image: S Friend]

Comment: Heck, this one's even better. Again, thanks for the fixes!

Comment: This ought to become a better meme then the bludgeoning one!