# Pluralization issue in the "Tags", "Responses" & "Votes" tabs on the Activity page

Tags: bug, status-completed, plurals, activity

On the Activity page, in the "Tags" tab, there's a pluralization issue (see "1 posts"):

[image]

---

There's another pluralization issue in the "Votes" tab (see "1 Votes"):

[image]

In my profile, currently, the issue is in the "Deletion" and "Undelete" subtabs, but I assume this occurs in all the subtabs.

---

Yet another pluralization issue in the "Responses" tab (see "1 Answers"):

[image]

Again, I assume this occurs in the all the subtabs in the "Responses" tab.

Comment: Seeing "4 score" in our interface makes me want to see that listed next to a post from 7 years ago... :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Cleaned up a lot of strings on the user activity page, including the ones you mentioned.

#### Thanks for bringing this to our attention! - Here's an S Friend

[image: S friend]

### Fixes

#### Pluralization fixes on summary screen

[image: Pluralization fixes on summary screen]

#### Pluralization fixes on bounties count

[image: Pluralization fixes on bounties count]

#### Pluralization fixes on section title

[image: Pluralization fixes on section title]

#### Pluralization fixes on tags post count

[image: Pluralization fixes on tags post count]

Comment: This image is definetly worthy of an upvote

Comment: Hi Kyle. Thanks for the fixes! Could *this* post and [Pluralization issue: "View all 1 bounties"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/376850/pluralization-issue-view-all-1-bounties) be marked as [status-completed]?

Comment: Yep, caught that one in this cleanup as well - thanks, I'll respond to that issue and mark as closed.  Just gotta draw another S friend

Comment: Hi Kyle. Could you also take a look at these pluralization issues in the Impact summary? [Pluralization issues in the Impact summary](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/379996/pluralization-issues-in-the-impact-summary)

Comment: @Justin - fix pushed up now

Comment: @Kyle: Thanks for the update! I was looking forward to that S friend ;)