# Input box keeps snapping to the bottom of the text when writing a new post or editing it

Tags: bug, edits, mobile-web, posting

Since [Deprecating our mobile views](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/367609/349643), I have noticed an annoying bug affecting **writing or editing answer or question posts on a mobile phone**.

If you are in the middle of a long portion of text, if you pause for a second or two, the input box snaps right back down to the bottom of the text, and then you have to scroll back up to see where you were.

Yesterday, it took me way more time than it should for a few simple edits, because typing then reviewing what was typed involved having to keep scrolling back up to the editing point.

This is particularly problematic in the stacks where references are required, and there is a list of references on the bottom.

I don't know if this is a javascript page refreshing issue or something along this line, (`draft saved` often pops up under the input box at this point).

I have android 12 installed and tried different android browsers

- Chrome (version 98.0.4758.101)
- Firefox (version 97.1.0 build #2015860771)
- Samsung Internet (version 16.0.6.230)

and the same thing happens in all of them.

Going back and making tweaks to this question here has done the same, so it is not site specific. Try deleting the 2 asterisks in the edit box toward the top of this question and moving it to the middle of that section. The box will snap to the bottom before you get the chance to complete the task.

I have a few big edits to make, and I am definitely not going to do that until I am at a computer. It would take me all day on one edit if I did it on my mobile. That's if the edit was completed before I launched my mobile across the room I am in.

Can this please be sorted? It is not a good user experience.

**Update:  I tried again to reproduce the problem**, and the problem no longer happens in Chrome and Firefox, but does continue in Samsung Internet.

Strange as no updates or cache clearance was performed.  I tried a cache clearance on Samsung Internet, just in case, and the problem persists.

Comment: Unable to reproduce, Chrome on android [Huawei]. The text stays exactly where it is at for me. Perhaps you could include some details about your system.

Comment: @Luuklag - please see update for browser and android versions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> "Update: I tried again to reproduce the problem, and the problem no longer happens in Chrome and Firefox, but does continue in Samsung Internet."

Great! Out of those three, Chrome and Firefox are the only browsers in [this list](https://browsers.stackoverflow.design/).

It has been made clear that browsers not in that list will not be supported, and not only that, but you also have to have one of the two most recent versions of the browser (see this FAQ: [Which browsers are officially supported, and what else do I need?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/56161/391772)).

In order to keep the sites excellent, it can be necessary to **focus** on the last two versions of the most popular browsers, rather than spreading resources thin by trying to support several versions of every browser.