# "Add a Comment" is broken on <site>/admin/dashboard

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, moderator-tools, flag-dashboard

The "Add a Comment" link on questions/answers on https://superuser.com/admin/dashboard is no longer working.

Clicking on it jumps to the top of the page. The link behind "Add a Comment" is `https://superuser.com/admin/dashboard#` on SuperUser.

Apparently the 'show 1 more comment' link doesn't work either.

Comment: Perhaps related: [Mast's answer to 'Deprecating our mobile views'](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/375231/986753).

Comment: Is this still not working for you? I tested it on SO and it appears to be working. Hmmm... scratch that. It's working under some conditions, but not others. I haven't tested enough to determine exactly which conditions are needed. However, within the last 16, or so, hours SE did push an update to how some of their internal functions are called and how the responses from some of their internal AJAX endpoints are organized. Some of these definitely affect how controls within the post are initialized. I'd consider it quite likely that's the cause (I know it's broken ~10 userscripts I use).

Comment: It's broken in multiple ways. I added a more detailed post to the Mod Team

Comment: The post on the Stack Moderators Team has been responded to – this issue (and related ones) should be fixed now.

Comment: @V2Blast Thx. Confirmed as fixed.

Comment: @V2Blast It's broken again :/

Comment: @DavidPostill: I've just tested, and it seems to be working to me as long as you let the page finish loading first. Can you confirm whether that's the case?

Comment: No. Broken when page is fully loaded (also when scripts are disabled).

Comment: Related (now fixed as well): [Buttons on Flagged Comments do not work on Moderator Tools Page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/376943/335251)