# Buttons on Flagged Comments do not work on Moderator Tools Page

Tags: bug, status-completed, comments, moderator-tools, comment-flags

I noticed today when reviewing a flagged comment on Arqade's Moderators Tools page (`/admin/dashboard`), I could not use any of the buttons on the comment itself to perform any action, including:

- Flag it
- Use the delete button on the comment itself
- Edit the comment
- Vote up the comment

When I tried to vote on the comment as a test, it scrolls the page way up as well.  I was still able to review and handle the comment just fine using the below controls.

Not that I actually wanted to perform any of the actions listed above for the comment, but the functionality should be the same.

[image: Buttons not working]

Comment: Supposedly, these issues were fixed at ~ 09:35Z yesterday.

Comment: @Makyen is there a post about this? I have to wait until another comment gets flagged to test out the cache issue.

Comment: @TimothyG. There was one here that is likely related ([here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/376815/add-a-comment-is-broken-on-site-admin-dashboard)) and one on the moderator Team.

Comment: Yeah. The issue from the linked question is fixed (and I've tested it to make sure). This one seems to be outstanding as far as I can tell.

Comment: @Catija seems awfully related indeed.  I didn't try to actually post a comment, only press the button in the .gif and it seemed to work.  That post describes the same behavior of scrolling to the top of the page too.

Comment: Yeah, the flag and edit buttons don't work. The "Add a comment" button (for me, on SO) does work... so it's not everything that's borked.

Comment: @Catija add a comment worked for me briefly after the fix was announced but is now broken again on [su]

Comment: @DavidPostill Should be working now - looks like Adam fixed it. Let us know if it's still behaving poorly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thanks for the report!

Should be all fixed now, but please let me know if anything is still off about expanded posts.

Comment: Confirmed as fixed - for the moment anyway :)