# Can we make post editors and answerers more visually distinct?

Tags: feature-request, design, accessibility, user-card, original-poster

I genuinely mistook a post editor for a post answerer. Admittedly this was on mobile view (the layout, not the alternative site mode, as that [mode has been removed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/367609/deprecating-our-mobile-views) as far as I can tell) but it's also not clear in desktop view either.

I blurred out the only content indicating the users action on a post, to show how easy this mistake it to make:

[image: two answers with 'edited by' and 'answered by' blurred out. A third image shows ones of the posts has been edited and two user cards shown.]

Part of the issue was the order the users are stacked in, and although chronologically it makes some sense, if you happen to not scroll enough it's confusing.

Desktop view also relied heavily on ordering:

[image: a post in desktop view with two users shown in a row. One is the editor and the other is the poster.]

Question askers get highlighting in both modes:

[image: mobile view: user cards for editor and asker. The asker is visually distinct]

[image: desktop view: user cards for editor and asker. The asker is visually distinct]

I made this issue because I'm dumb and I rushed and didn't fully scroll. But somebody who is visually impaired but doesn't rely on a screen reader could easily make the same mistake.

Can we have some better styling/indicators to improve this?

Comment: Just be glad we've gotten rid of all those alternative views (apps, mobile site) that put the editor and author in every arrangement possible. (But yeah, I agree.)

Comment: If nothing else, the editor should go below the author so that when we're scrolling, we always see the author in the same place. I prefer them to be side-by-side though.

Comment: Just as an anecdote, I've frequently had people (e.g. in D&D communities I'm a part of) – mainly, not regular Stack Exchange users, but those finding Q&As from search results – mistakenly think that a post they come across was written by me, when in fact it was merely edited by me. (I have edited a lot of posts on RPG.SE...)

Comment: No, it is not dumbness. It is actual [usability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Usability) data—information about how the software is *actually* being used by *actual users* in an *actual* usage scenario, in contrast to some idealised imagined scenario.

Comment: It *literally* says "edited" just above the editor's user card. What more do you want? How protected should things be from people just not reading or paying attention? I know you've brought up the issue of visually impaired people using the site without relying on a screen reader, and I don't want to distract from that possible issue or the real and significant issues which exist for the visually impaired, but what do you propose would help in this instance without substantially overwhelming the page with formatting?

Comment: One thing to consider as a way to handle this is to have a "this post has not been edited" entry in the edited by location on every unedited post (which also links to the edit history, as the edit history page is sometimes useful, even when there's only one version). That "this post has not been edited" entry would then always consume a space in the layout. Thus, even when pages are displayed at narrow screen widths there will be a consistent placement for the author, rather than having a substantially different placement depending on if the post has been edited, or not.

Comment: @Makyen I'm aware of what it says on the page. It's a tiny bit of CSS changes to reorder them. But that's not a great solution in my eyes. I'm asking for input, not to get a fix I'm aware of implemented

Comment: IMO, reversing the order of the editor and the original author doesn't make sense. The post and the attributions can be equated to wrappers around the content. The outer wrapper, which contains everything, is attributed to the original author. Within that is the attribution for the most recent editor and a link to all versions with attribution for each revision. At least to me, it doesn't make sense to have the outer wrapper be attributed to the most recent editor.